# "make docker-image" having troubles with python3.8-minimal

Tags: docker-image, ubuntu-22.04

I was doing a containerlab lab for university and ran into this problem: I needed to create a docker image for chr-6.47.9.vmdk, placed in the routeros folder from the project https://github.com/hellt/vrnetlab. I went to the routeros directory (localy of course, I cloned the vrnetlab folder to usr folder) and ran **sudo make docker-image**, and got the following error:

```
42.76 Get:308 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 ssh-import-id all 5.10-0ubuntu1 [10.0 kB]
42.85 debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
42.87 Fetched 90.3 MB in 29s (3079 kB/s)
42.89 Selecting previously unselected package libssl1.1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 4124 files and directories currently installed.)
42.90 Preparing to unpack .../libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.20_amd64.deb ...
42.90 Unpacking libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.20) ...
42.99 Selecting previously unselected package libpython3.8-minimal:amd64.
42.99 Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9_amd64.deb ...
43.00 Unpacking libpython3.8-minimal:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9) ...
43.06 Selecting previously unselected package libexpat1:amd64.
43.06 Preparing to unpack .../libexpat1_2.2.9-1ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb ...
43.06 Unpacking libexpat1:amd64 (2.2.9-1ubuntu0.6) ...
43.09 Selecting previously unselected package python3.8-minimal.
43.09 Preparing to unpack .../python3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9_amd64.deb ...
43.10 Unpacking python3.8-minimal (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9) ...
43.23 Setting up libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.20) ...
43.29 Setting up libpython3.8-minimal:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9) ...
43.30 Setting up libexpat1:amd64 (2.2.9-1ubuntu0.6) ...
43.30 Setting up python3.8-minimal (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9) ...
43.38 Traceback (most recent call last):
43.38   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py", line 215, in <module>
43.38     sys.exit(main())
43.38   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py", line 207, in main
43.38     compile(filename, doraise=True)
43.38   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py", line 172, in compile
43.38     importlib._bootstrap_external._write_atomic(cfile, bytecode, mode)
43.38   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 186, in _write_atomic
43.38 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-38.pyc.140090424139424'
43.38 dpkg: error processing package python3.8-minimal (--configure):
43.38  installed python3.8-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
43.39 Errors were encountered while processing:
43.39  python3.8-minimal
43.41 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update -qy    && apt-get upgrade -qy    && apt-get install -y    bridge-utils    iproute2    python3-ipy    socat    qemu-kvm    tcpdump    ssh    inetutils-ping    dnsutils    iptables    nftables    telnet    ftp    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*]: exit code: 100
make[1]: *** [../makefile.include:29: docker-build-common] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/shunya19/vrnetlab/routeros'
make: *** [../makefile.include:9: docker-image] Error 2
```

So, I paid attention to the **python3.8-minimal** file and tried reinstalling it. After some time I managed to install python3.8 again (I guess Ubuntu 22.04 no more have it installed) and now ls /usr/bin/python* shows both python3.8 and python3.10, but still problem won't go away.

I also thought that it might be the privilege issue - then I used **su root**, but anyway, **no result.** I will gladly give any helping information, really want to figure out what is wrong (btw there is no helping info on that error in lab, it is just simple steps "clone repo -> add .vmdk -> make image" so I am here)

ubuntu version: 22.04

p.s. I've just recently updated Ubuntu, maybe it is somehow connected to the error.